# LEAD AND LAG NOT working in mysql workbench 8.0.22

Tags: mariadb, window-functions, lag, lead

I have just updated my workbench to latest version just to run lead and lag window functions

But it is still giving following error
Error code 1305 function lead does not exist

Comment: Have you tried completely exiting and restarting Workbench?  Maybe some part of the old engine is still running.

Comment: MySQL workbench is just a UI tool, not the database itself. Just to be on the safe side... are you connecting to a MySQL 5.x or 8.x? Run `select version();` to verify.

Comment: i am connected to 8.x

just updated it

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen it restarted itself....

Comment: 1) Show the output of the `select version();` statement. 2) Add the query you want to run, or a simplified version of it.

Comment: The version it showed is 10.1.37-MariaDB

is it compatible?

and here is the query
```
SELECT Description,lead(Description) over()FROM DbAssignment.`e-commerce` 
```

Comment: Read https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions/ and see that MariaDB doesn't support window functions until version 10.2.0.